# docker commit influxdb - no changes in result image

Tags: docker, containers, influxdb

I have big problem with influxdb docker image. I want to save data, databases and tables to file, move file to another host and then restore container with full configuration and data. I tied:

```
1. docker save / load
2. docker export / import
3. docker commit / run
```

For influxdb official docker image commands above don't save changes... Everytime container was "clean" with only initial configuration. I have no idea what is wrong... command:

```
docker diff
```

only confirms that no changes was saved.

Thank You for Your time and answers.

Comment: Do you have mounted volumes in your orginal container that you want to commit?

Comment: no, I have only few databases/rows in influxdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount volumes at database location:

```
docker run -p 8083:8083 -p 8086:8086 \
      -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb \
      influxdb
```

This will mount current location as bind mount to `/var/lib/influxdb`in the container (this is where influxdb stores databases.) Then you can tarball the bind mount on docker host and move it to the new host.

Now To the problem:

InfluxDB's `Dockerfile` declares `/var/lib/influxdb` as a volume. Volumes are not affected with `docker commit`.

```
VOLUME /var/lib/influxdb
```

Comment: ok, i tried Your solution, but there is nothing in connected volume... and there is nothing in containers `/var/lib/influxdb`. Binding itself works - I created one file and it was copied do my path. Maybe I must commit something in influx?

Comment: Sorry - You where right :) everything is fine now. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to save some changes in the influxdb (commit) and starting a new container using the new Image created.
Let me list down the steps I took:

1. docker pull influxdb -----> image: 646d62fcef78
2. docker run -ti influxdb /bin/bash ----> container C1
3. In C1: mkdir ~/testing123
4. Ctrl+p+q ----> Get out of the container
5. docker commit C1 ----> 30d103f44698
6. docker tag 30d103f44698 new_influxdb ----> Tag the new image
7. docker run -ti new_influxdb /bin/bash  ----> Container C2

In C2, When I checked the change that I made (~/testing123), I was able to see that it was present.

You might be using the same image. A new Image is created after the docker commit.

P.S.: Couldn't comment, that's why had to post it as an answer.

Comment: problem isn't with directiories - there everything is fine... problem is with data in influxDB

Comment: Ok, I have hardly any experience with influxDB. But why don't you: [1]add data in influxDB, [2]Exit the container (stop it), [3]Use "docker start" to start that container again, and see if the data is retained. 

That way we could be sure that if it's related to container part or image part.